# "Append if doesn't exists" in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a helper function for jQuery that creates an element if it doesn't already exist. So far I have:

```
function setup(element, parent){
  if($(parent).child(element).length == 0){
    $(parent).append('<div class="'+element+'"></div>');
  }
}
```

but I'm wondering if this isn't a solved problem. Is it?

(The reason I want this is so I can pull in JSON content and put it in the right place. If the right place exists, I'll just update the content. If it doesn't exist, I'll create it.)

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `element` to be the class name then you also need to use the class selector for testing:

```
function setup(className, parent) {
    if ($(parent).children("."+className).length == 0) {
        $(parent).append("<div></div>").children(":last-child").addClass(className);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming You identify Your divs with id and have an array of elements with ids as keys

```
function mergeIn(elements,parent){
 $(parent).children('div').each(function(){
  $(this).html(elements[$(this).attr('id')]); 
  delete elements[$(this).attr('id')]; 
 });
 //only not present elements remain in the array
 for(var i in elements){
  $(parent).append('<div id="'+i+'">'+elements[i]+'</div>');
 }
}
```

and it's all done :)